# Programming lanuage for Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, gui

I made a small program for work at a tech support job. Consists mostly of hotkeys to autotype out commonly used commands (Instead of typing *passowrd* 50 times, just press your desired hotkey) and an edit box/text box to write notes in and it automatically saves them in a text file with the name as the date (2014-26-9.txt) so you don't have to constantly save it yourself. Only problem is the program is made in AutoIt. Great language to make small stuff like this but a couple of the other guys uses Linux and AutoIt doesn't work in Linux.

I know a fair bit of C++ (Anything I don't know I can research) so anything closely related to this works. Python is probably my first choice (I know it's cross-platform and C-like), and I can do most of the figuring out myself, but can someone point me in the direction to making the GUI?

It'll pretty much be select the hotkey you want for that command (I.e., F1, F2, F3, Delete, PgUp etc), when you press that key it sends a string and there's a text box you can write in and it will automatically save the text box to a .txt file when you close the program.

Comment: Could you be more specific? As it stands, you question can have any number of answers each depending on the personal preferences of the answerer. We don't like that. What kind of GUI do you want? Would a text-based GUI be OK? Otherwise, just use your favorite language. Java, Perl, Python, C even.

Comment: I'm wanting a language that is simple enough to not take a week to write but I can run on Linux and Windows without (too much) modification. Text-based is fine, it's what AI was (GUICreate("Title",width,height,styles)). The QT designer was awesome, much faster, but I was not able to use the generated .py file.

Comment: Python will definitely work, I'm not struggling with it. Went ahead and used wxPython for the GUI. Had a small GUI designer (since I wasn't able to import the .py from Qt Designer). And the reason I said "not take a week" is because it's one text box, 1 menu, sub menus and then a few menu items for each sub menu.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.4](http://python.org/downloads) with [`PyQt 5`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and of course [`Qt5`](http://qt-project.org/qt5) have been great for me, especially with Qt Designer. All of these are cross-platform and work on Linux. What you have said is possible with modules such as `pickle`. If you don't want to download anything extra for Python `tkinter` is also available. As for C++ you can easily use Qt5 as well.

Comment: Went ahead and used the QT Designer and made a gui but whenever I try to convert it to .py using "pyuic NEKDesign.ui > NEK.py" I get the error "ImportError: no module named PyQt5".

Comment: I think you need to write "pyuic5 NEKDesign.ui > NEK.py". If that doesn't work try reinstall PyQt. Sorry for late response, by the way

Comment: Just gonna go with wxPython.... Designer made it really easy but very useless if I can't import the code, managed to convert it to .py but can't use it.

Comment: Ok, but if you can't use the application check for it trying to import "<filename>_rc". This breaks the code. If this isn't present make sure the application can be run by adding the executer at the end (if name == main).